# How to use For In loop on a list within a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-lists

So, I need to use a for i in loop on a list that is within a list.  Let me give you an example.
I have a blacklist (list) that contains 10 categories (also lists), in those categories, there are always 2 ints.
I also have a list called x. x contains 2 ints.
I want to check if the 2 ints inside x are the same as any of the blacklist categories.
In order to do that I need to do

```
def blacklist_check(blacklist, z):
    for i in blacklist:
        for y in blacklist[i]:
            difference = blacklist[i][y] - z
            if difference < 10 and difference > -10:
                print(f"{difference} found")
                return False
            print(f"{difference} not found")
            if i == 10:
                return True
```

but when I try that I get

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

I can not transfer the categories to ints or any other type than lists. How do I make this work?

Comment: Just `for y in i` and `difference = y - z`. Note that `i` is the element in the `blacklist`, not their index.

Comment: @MechanicPig Please post this as an answer.

Comment: @MeLikeFish First debug your program to see what is going on. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) has some great tips to get you started. Then if you still need help post a new quesiton with the current version of your code. Be sure to explicitly explain what "it always returns None" means. Usually with some example output.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I found the issue, wanted to edit the comment but it didn't let me. Thank you for the reply though

Comment: @MeLikeFish Thanks for letting me know.  You can only edit a  comment within a few minutes of posting it. But you can and should delete comments if they are no longer relevant or helpful. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here **(y)** is a list, you cannot nest a list as a index inside another list.
**Try this**

```
def blacklist_check(blacklist, z):
    for i in blacklist:
        for y in range(len(i)):
            difference = i[y] - z
            if difference < 10 and difference > -10:
                print(f"{difference} found")
                return False
            print(f"{difference} not found")
            if i == 10:
                return True
```

Comment: I think you mean that `i` is a list, not `(y)`. Also `i[y]` should change to `y`.

Comment: Yes, also can use (range and len) function Like the example above

Comment: Yes, that works, too. In Python, we prefer `for x in my_list` as much as possible and don't use `range()` very much.

Answer (score 0):

Python handles for loops differently to perhaps a more conventional C-Type language in that it runs based on enumeration rather than incrementation.

In your case, what you have with `for i in blacklist`, for each iteration of the for loop, `i` is set to the **element** rather than the index, so if your data structure looks something like:

```
[ [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8] ]
```

Then the first value of `i` will be `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, and is hence a list. If you want the indexes rather than the elements, you could use the `range` and `len` functions in the following way:

```py
for i in range(len(blacklist)):
```

which will make `i` be `0` on the first iteration, and `1` on the second one, etc.

That would mean that calling `blacklist[i]` will return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't consider the printed statements in the sample code, the simplest way to write it should be to use `any` with generator expression:

```
def blacklist_check(blacklist, z):
    return not any(abs(y - z) < 10 for cls in blacklist for y in cls)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
def blacklist_check(blacklist, z):
    for cls in blacklist:
        for y in cls:
            if abs(y - z) < 10:   # same as -10 < (y - z) < 10
                return False
    return True
```

Note that since `i` in your code does not represent the index of the element in the `blacklist`, you should not judge whether it is the last element by `i == 10`, but should directly return `True` after the end of the for loop.